# How do I debug/launch program that has argument containing "<" and ">"

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a program that processes HTML content. With a command line argument I can feed it test strings.

From the Windows command line (cmd.exe) I can run it without problems using

```
C:\Python36\python.exe program.py -t "<head><title>Test</title></head>"
```

I can't get a launch config that will pass this argument correctly.

I get the following errors

```
< was unexpected at this time.
```

or

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Which file it is looking for is not mentioned

The problem might be caused by the fact that everything is passed as an argument to cmd inside quotes.

I use the standard `Python: Current File` config with an `args` option added

```
    {
      "name": "Python: Debug with args",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "args" : ["-t","<head><title>Test</title></head>"]
    }
```

Adding quotes with single escape

```
"args" : ["-t","\"<head><title>Test</title></head>\""]
```

or double escape (found in C++ launch documentation)

```
"args" : ["-t","\\\"<head><title>Test</title></head>\\\""]
```

did not solve the problem.

---

**Edit**

Partial solution, only works in a **new Terminal**:

Add a space in the argument string ==> VSC escapes the argument in double quotes

```
"args" : ["-t","<head><title>Test</title> </head>"]
```

I once read some documentation about letting VSC wrap the argument in single or double quotes. But I can't find this doc anymore in the current version.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to setup your args more like this :

```
"args" : '-t "<head><title>Test</title></head>"'
```

instead of

```
"args" : ["-t","<head><title>Test</title></head>"]
```

Comment: the launch config file is json so strings need to be specified with double quotes ("), the `args` option need to be an array, and if I use `"args" : [ "-t \"<head><title>Test</title></head>\"" ]` I get double quotes **inside** my argument and it is combined with the `-t` in the same argument. argparse then gives me the value of `-t` as ` "<head><title>Test</title></head>"` (watch the space and the double quotes). All this on the first run in the terminal, next runs give me the `cmd` version of starting the debugger

Comment: And did you try to add \ before all your < and > characters ? 
I mean, try to escape < and >, and not your double quotes.

Comment: Yes I have and it is not recognized by JSON removed by parser, It never gets to the command. That is not needed if you look at my partial solution. What is needed is correct adding of quotes so it will pass the constructed debugger command. Both versions of the debugger command. I can kill the terminal after every launch (not ideal).